# What are the minimum privileges of oracle user to create database and execure pending migrations in EF6 Code First

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-6, code-first, database-administration, privileges

while upedating database with EF6 Code first with ORACLE  migrations gives error  like this.

> ORA-00604 : error occurred at recursive SQL LEVEL 1 \nORA-06519:active autonomous transaction detected and rolled back\nORA-065212 "

same operation worked good in our development servers. but in our customer server it does not work.

i have a doubt about user Privileges.

user in our development server 
GRANTED ROLES  => CONNECT (GRANTED,DEFAULT),DBA (GRANTED,DEFAULT)
System Privileges => UNLIMITED TABLESPACE (GRANTED)

user in privileges in customer server
GRANTED ROLES  => CONNECT (DEFAULT),Resource(DEFAULT)
System Privileges => UNLIMITED TABLESPACE()

i searched on internet but i could not find anything , What is the minimum user  privileges for create database and update pending migrations in EF 6 code first for oracle

Comment: it depends on [what you do](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqljgrant.html), do you: 1) simply populating existing table, 2) creates new table, 3) alter existing table, 4) drop existing tables, 5) add foreign keys, 6) creates new database? on some case someone might throw in function/procedure generation on the migration.

Comment: i can do this operations manualy on server, but db update gives error 
can you offer anything else ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pertinent line from the error stack :

> ORA-06519:active autonomous transaction detected and rolled back.

This is a design problem and not anything to do with privileges.

Somewhere in your code you have a `pragma autonomous_transaction` defined in a program unit which doesn't have a COMMIT or ROLLBACK. An autonomous transaction cannot run past the end of the program unit and so must be committed (or rolled back) before then. If the program flow reaches the end of the unit without committing Oracle hurls ORA-06519.

The solution is to comb through your code, find the autonomous transaction and with remove it or add the necessary commit. Which option is correct depends upon the business logic you're trying to implement. I find `pragma autonomous_transaction` tends to be abused as a kludge for a broken data model or flawed business logic. Unless you're logging or auditing, the better solution is likely to be removal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer 
but i tested same operation both "Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production" and 
"Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production" it worked without problem. 

our customer uses 11.2.0.4.0  version

Comment: I can only tell you the cause of the error stack you posted. Perhaps your customer has a different version of the database code from what you're running? Maybe the error you posted is not the real error and you need to search the logs again?